# VHDL: genric map setup

Tags: vhdl

Why would this setup work?

```
component mux2to1 is
generic (M    : integer := 1);    -- Number of bits in the inputs and   output
port (input0  : in  m32_vector(M-1 downto 0) := (others => '0');
      input1  : in  m32_vector(M-1 downto 0) := (others => '0');
      sel     : in  m32_1bit;
      output  : out m32_vector(M-1 downto 0));
end component;
```

The way I understand genric map is (M: integer: 1) would specify the bit of port to be 1 through out but when M-1 downto 0 would just be 0 down 0, which makes no sense.

Comment: You can have an array that has 0, 1 or more elements. (0 downto 0) would have 1 element.  See IEEE Std 1076-2008 5.3.2 Array types, 5.3.2.2 Index constraints and discrete ranges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @user1155120 said, you can have an array that has 1 element. (0 downto 0) would have 1 element.

There is another important point to make, however:

In VHDL an array of 1 element of a certain type is not the same type as the element type. So, for example, `std_logic` and `std_logic_vector(0 downto 0)` are different types. You cannot assign one to the other. `std_logic` is a scalar whilst `std_logic_vector(0 downto 0)` is an array type.

To "convert" between these types, you need to index the array type. So, with signals

```
signal S : std_logic;
signal A : std_logic_vector(0 downto 0);
```

you cannot assign A to S or visa versa, but you can do this:

```
A(0) <= S;
```

or this:

```
S <= A(0);
```

You can also index array ports. So, with

```
entity HAS_ARRAY_PORT
  port ( P : in std_logic_vector(0 downto 0));
end;
```

You can do this:

```
L: entity work.HAS_ARRAY_PORT port map (P(0) => S);
```

Comment: You could also say std_logic and std_logic_vector are different types and an indexed named denotes and element of an array. In this case the base type of the array element is the same as the base type of std_logic. See IEEE Std 1076-2008 8.4 Indexed names and the package declaration for std_logic_1164.

Comment: so does generic (M    : integer := 1) mean we assign M to 1 and input 0 would just be one element but the data type has not assigned yet? Like it can be word or 1 bit or anything else?

Comment: @Zac Uwyo H generic (M : integer := 1) means you have an array of one element of type m32_vector.